# Why was my 'not-an-answer' flag disputed, when a mod actually deleted the answer?

Tags: support, flagging

Yesterday I flagged [this (now deleted) answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6853/what-plot-points-are-missing-in-the-harry-potter-movies-that-are-in-the-novels/71771#71771) as 'not-an-answer' and I had my flag disputed.

[image]

But, today I saw that the answer was

> deleted by Darth Satan, Pureferret♦ 11 hours ago

So my question is: Why did a moderator dispute my flag when another (or the same) had the post deleted?

If the post was deleted for actually not being an answer, wasn't my flag correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your flag was automatically dismissed as a result of that question's trip through the Low Quality review queue. [Info on that process is on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861).

Comment: So a flag can be disputed by the review queue and declined by a mod?

Comment: A flag can only be dismissed once, a mod can mark helpful or declined; or the review queue can automatically mark it helpful, disputed, or declined.